# run another instance of the program within the same program's code with new static parameters in java

Tags: java, static, multiple-instances

I have a program and I want that if the user clicks on a "open new instance" button, the whole program will open again.
I tried that:
WelcomeFrame.main(new String[0]);
(while WelcomeFrame is the first jFrame of the program).
But while I try to access a static parameter from the two instances of the running program I see that this parameter is the same (and I must have two insatnces of that parameter).
How can I implement that in JAVA?

Comment: You may want to turn your WelcomeFrame into an object. You can then create as many WelcomeFrame that you want

Comment: either get rid of `static` or really start a new independant jvm process along the lines of https://wiki.cantara.no/display/dev/Start+a+new+JVM+from+Java . But getting rid of `static` is cleaner code because exactly what you experience and it should be easier once you understand how it works. Also way more robust because starting programs can fail in so many ways.

Comment: I tried 1:  
`String jvm = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";  
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");  
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();  
command.add(jvm);  
command.add(WelcomeFrame.class.toString());  
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);  
Map<String, String> environment = processBuilder.environment();  
environment.put("CLASSPATH", classpath);  
processBuilder.start();`  
  
and it didn't work, I still get shared static parameter from both insances.

Comment: I tried 2:  
`public class Main extends Object{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  WelcomeFrame.main(null);
 }
}`
   
and it didn't work, I still get shared static parameter from both insances.
@user3170251

Comment: About the non static solution, I didnt understand how to implement that.  
I have a "Tournament" class that is singeton, and have a static getInstance() function.  
what I should change?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into impmeneting a thread. I think it can solve your problem here. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: threads share static variable contents too, that's not going to help